# Using history api with ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html5-history

I'm attempting to do `history.replaceState()` inside reactjs but I'm getting errors. How do I work with the history api inside a reactjs app?

Comment: Can you be more specifc about how you're trying to use it and what the error is?

Comment: I think I found the solution by using `react-route-dom`

Comment: Can you please specify what you wanted to do exactly. If you have found the solution, please post it as answer.

Answer (score 1):

To make use of history (react-router-dom) you need to import it.

```
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
```

Then in your code you will do:

```
export default () => {
    const history = useHistory();
 
    return <button onClick={() => history.goBack()}>Go back</button>
}
```

Use history. then the method you want to use.